# Who am I that you might ask?

Tags: riddle, rhyme

**I am faster than you can run,**
*so abandon me, go home and have fun.*
**I live where the moon rise from above,**
*so abandon me, get rid of the hands in glove.*

**I am soft like a kitty** *and hard like a rock,*
**without any warning we come in flock.**
Who am I that you might ask?
**a symbol of fear,** hidden in a mask!

Hints:

> Every line is a hint, there are no word plays and there are more than one references.  Also, I **bold** and *italic* some lines for a reason~

Hint #2:

> 2 words from the first 2 lines gives you enough hints when combined with the lines

Comment: Question is updated to give more hints.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the answer is

> Baseball Bat/Bats

*I am faster than you can run,

so abandon me, go home and have fun.*

> From **Chronos**: *The second hint given is "home run" which would be a reference to Baseball*

*I live where the moon rise from above*

> Bats are hanging upside down

*so abandon me, get rid of the hands in glove.*

> From **Chronos**: *hands in glove would mean the gloves you use in baseball*

*I am soft like a kitty and hard like a rock,*

> Bats have fur so you can call them soft as a kitty and hard as a rock because... "*baseball bats are hard*"

*without any warning we come in flock.*

> Bats come in flock, that's true

*Who am I that you might ask?

a symbol of fear, hidden in a mask!*

> Bats are scary and "*a mask*" is a reference to Batman :)

Half of the credits are going to **Chronos** from the commet below.

Comment: It seems the lines in bold refer to animal bat and the italic ones to a baseball bat.

Comment: I think it's bat too. The second hint given is **"home run"** which would be a reference to Baseball. Moon rise might mean this is nocturnal, hands in glove would mean the gloves you use in baseball; bats are soft creatures, while baseball bats are hard. Bats are flying creatures so I think you could use the word 'flock' to refer to them collectively. Symbol of fear hidden in a mask would be a reference to Batman-- a symbol of fear in Gotham and the masked Dark knight

Comment: @Chronos nicely done!  I will wait for Marin to update his answer before accepting.

Comment: @MarinTakanov it is correct, but you are missing some of the explanations.  See Chronos's answer

Comment: @MarinTakanov Thanks I will accept this answer.  Also, the explanation I am looking for from " I live where the moon rise from above", is the fact that bats are hanging upside down

Answer (score 2):

I think it is

> Wolves

I am faster than you can run,

> They are fast

so abandon me, go home and have fun.

> In Chinese, a "wolf"色狼 is considered sexually perverted. So someone who is a 色狼 go home and have fun

I live where the moon rise from above,

> They howl at the moon and are pretty active at night.

so abandon me, get rid of the hands in glove.

> Not too sure about this one... maybe wolfskin gloves?

I am soft like a kitty and hard like a rock,

> They are furry, but strong and dangerous

without any warning we come in flock.

> They stalk their preys and hunt in packs

Who am I that you might ask?
a symbol of fear, hidden in a mask!

> They are a symbol of fear in multiple cultures. 
> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolves_in_folklore,_religion_and_mythology

Comment: Good guess but not the answer.  It will be too specific to riddle a line that only known to certain cultures =D.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of the lines could fit

> **the sea**.

*I am faster than you can run,

 so abandon me, go home and have fun.*

> Sea is a homophone of **c**, which represents the speed of light - much faster than anyone can run.

*I live where the moon rise from above,

 so abandon me, get rid of the hands in glove.*

> In the sea, the moon appears as a reflection. When the moon rises, its reflection starts at the horizon and moves *downwards*. "Hands in glove" could also be a reference to reflections: a hand and its glove, like the moon and its reflection, are very similar to each other yet subtly different.

*I am soft like a kitty and hard like a rock,*

> The sea can be soft and gentle when calm, but it's deadly in a storm, when the impact of fast-moving water can feel like a rock.

*without any warning we come in flock.*

> Waves can come in flocks.

*Who am I that you might ask?

 a symbol of fear, hidden in a mask!*

> From [this source](http://followtherabbi.com/journey/israel/when-storms-come): "In Jesus' day, Jewish people feared large bodies of water. They referred to the sea as an abyss and saw it as a symbol of chaos and hell." I'm not sure about the mask bit.

Comment: @randalthor Not the answer but I like your explanations, especially the one with moon rise from above, it's poetic.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is,

> cloud

I am faster than you can run

> they run faster some times.

I live where the moon rise from above

> Not Sure about this line

I am soft like a kitty and hard like a rock,

> Cloud are soft and hard like rock when it create electricity and sounds like rock .

without any warning we come in flock

> They have not sound and they come in flock (looks like flock)

Comment: Nice attempt but that's not the answer~

Answer (score 1):

I guess the answer is

> **SNOW**

I am faster than you can run,

> It falls from sky in pace and it is difficult to run in snow.

so abandon me, go home and have fun.

> We usually stay at home when it is snowing

I live where the moon rise from above,

> Snow is formed in clouds, where the moon rises.

so abandon me, get rid of the hands in glove.

> Because it's cold we wear gloves.

I am soft like a kitty and hard like a rock,

> It is soft(snowflakes) or hard (Hail, Ice Pellets or Snow grains)

without any warning we come in flock.

> It starts suddenly and is often heavy

Who am I that you might ask?
a symbol of fear, hidden in a mask!

> Cant make sense of this... :(

***EDIT***

Is it

> **RAIN**

for same explanation

Comment: Good guess but that's not the answer I am looking for

Comment: And nope, not rain either

Answer (score 0):

I think it is:

> A skeleton

I am faster than you can run,

> Your skeleton runs at the same speed as you, but can do other things (like ride in a car)... also the same speed as you, but faster than you can run (since you too ride in a car faster than you can run).

so abandon me, go home and have fun.

> A lot of people call the afterlife their true home and a happy place. If you abandon your skeleton, that's where you will go.

I live where the moon rise from above,

> Not sure

so abandon me, get rid of the hands in glove.

> Your hands are the glove here. Your skeleton's hands are in the 'gloves' of your skin-hands.

I am soft like a kitty and hard like a rock,

> Your skin is soft but your skeleton is hard.

without any warning we come in flock.

> Not sure, but people do come in 'flocks' sometimes. Also in horror movies a bunch of skeletons might fall on you without warning or something. Also a graveyard is a 'flock' of skeletons.

Who am I that you might ask?
a symbol of fear, hidden in a mask!

> Similar to the gloves one. A skeleton is a symbol of fear, and it's hidden in the 'mask' of your body.

Comment: Not the answer i'm looking for, but I like how you explain line 4, it's creative